# CalCalendarStore not found

Tags: iphone

I need to use CalCalendarStore but i'm not finding the header file or framework for it. I tried to find in /System/Library/Frameworks/CalendarStore.framework, but there's no framework with this name. What should I do?

regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CalCalendarStore` is only available on Mac OS, not iOS. iOS uses the [EventKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) API.